# print spooler service in ubuntu

Tags: networking

I want to share a printer under Ubuntu 11.04 with Windows 7.
I have installed `samba` and configured it to allow the printer to be browsed across the network.
I have also enabled printer sharing. But when I try to search the printer from Windows 7, it prompts me to start the print spooler in Ubuntu print server.
How can I start print spooler in Ubuntu?

I have also installed `cups` but not configured it yet. I am able to print from my Ubuntu client by using the same network printer in Ubunutu print server.
Can anybody help me to start the print spooler and solve this so that I can print in my Windows machine from the Linux print server.

Comment: Start the print spooler by entering `sudo start cups`. You can check if it is already running with `sudo status cups`.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Jos.I ahve started print spooler but even after doing the same I can not able to access the printer and print from Ubuntu.It is still asking me to start the print spooler.Can anybody help me